# ReactJs context - Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to use the new ReactJs Context, as an alternative to Redux, however I am getting an error of.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

**Here is the code for my layout which I have wrapped in the MyProvider tag**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavMenu } from "./NavMenu";
import { MyProvider } from "../contexts/context";

export class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyProvider>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <NavMenu />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-9">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </MyProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

**Here is the context code which I am importing**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export class MyProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        name: 'test name'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <MyContext.Provider value="{this.state}">
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

**Here is the place the provider is being consumed**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import { MyProvider } from "../contexts/context";

export class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="m-2">
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {(c) => (<p>My name is {c.state.name}</p>)}
            </MyContext.Consumer>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `NavMenu` exported correctly? Can you please show the code of it?

Comment: You are not using anywhere the `MyProvider.Consumer`.
`MyProvider` is the output of `React.createContext()` so not a valid React element by itself

Comment: Sorry I have used MyProvider.Consumer somewhere I just didn't add it to make the question shorter, I will amend

Comment: @LucaFabbri `MyProvider` is the react component. The naming is really confusing here. `MyContext` is the output of `React.createContext()`. @user3284707 You should fix this.

Comment: I unfortunately can not test this at the moment, but will update when I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me provide another answer. This is similar to @Tholle's but I think it is closer to your intention. If not, consider this as a simple alternative.

```
const MyContext = React.createContext()

class MyProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'test name'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyProvider>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-3">
            <NavMenu />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-9">
              {this.props.children}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="m-2">
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {c => <p>My name is {c.name}</p>}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Layout><Counter /></Layout>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have unfortunately not been able to test this yet. I will try this out later and then let you know.

Comment: I'm afraid this still isn;t working, i'm still getting the same error message "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Comment: Ok - so this isn't the exact error but something pretty similar, worked great when everything was in one js file, as soon as I moved the context out it then broke..?  https://codesandbox.io/s/9y1krp798w - EDIT - Actually I forgot to export so no wonder it didnt work...

Comment: Yes this does in this example... which annoyingly means it's something else... I'm using the visual studio template which has a load of other routing additions to it which may be causing issues

Comment: You said this does now work on your dev env right and same problem in the title? Then as @Hardik Modha asked is your `NavMenu` exported properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177366/discussion-between-user3284707-and-devserkan).

Comment: I wonder what caused the problem :) Sorry, I couldn't catch your last message on the chat.

Comment: I've found the reason, the dist folder had some old Typescript libraries hanging around.  Removing the dist folder and rebuilding has fixed the issue

Comment: Ah, then you are testing it after built. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes indeed! I am now stuck on the next part though... can you spare a few minutes to take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51686058/3284707

Comment: Despite that I seemed so familiar with React Context, actually I'm not :) I looked your other question and can't get your intention clearly. Maybe you can provide some more details with other parts of your app then maybe some master minds make some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `{this.state}` as value for the Provider, not `"{this.state}"`

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "test name"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

You also have to use the `MyContext.Consumer` component to use the `value` from the provider, and this component takes a function as child.

```
import { MyProvider, MyContext } from "../contexts/context";

export class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyProvider>
        <MyContext.Consumer>
          {value => (
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  <NavMenu />
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-9">{this.props.children}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </MyContext.Consumer>
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I am unable to test this at the moment but will let you know how I get on when I can later.

Comment: I'm afraid this still isn;t working, i'm still getting the same error message "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Comment: @user3284707 That's frustrating. Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new). There might be something else that is wrong.

Comment: Done a sample in codesandbox, not the exact error but very similar https://codesandbox.io/s/x93nnww22q- EDIT - Actually I forgot to export so no wonder it didnt work...

Comment: @user3284707 Ah, so the real issue was an export issue? Glad you found it.

Comment: actually unfortunately it wasn't, must be something else... the code works in codesandbox, but not on my dev environment :(

Comment: I've found the reason, the dist folder had some old Typescript libraries hanging around.  Removing the dist folder and rebuilding has fixed the issue