# ReactJs context - how to replace the current component state with the state passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-context

I am trying to get my head around ReactJs context, and have finally made some progress to display the state name and countNumber.

However I am still struggling to work out how to replace the current state, which is used in my formatCount() function.

Can anyone let me know how you would do this in my example below?

I would like to use the number in my context e.g. 5 in the method, formatCount(), so it would be something like

```
    formatCount() {
        const currentCount = {c.state.currentCount};
        return currentCount === 0 ? "Zero" : currentCount;
    }
```

[image]

**Here is my context**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export const CounterContext = React.createContext();

export default class CounterProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        state: { name: 'bob', currentCount: 5 },
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <CounterContext.Provider value={ this.state }>
                {this.props.children}
            </CounterContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

**Here is my counter component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import { CounterContext } from "../contexts/context.js";

export class Counter extends Component {
    state = { currentCount: 7 }

    render() {
        return <div className="m-2">
            <CounterContext.Consumer>
                {c =>
                    <div className="m-2">
                        <p>My name is {c.state.name} - {c.state.currentCount}</p>
                        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                        <button className="btn btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2" onClick={() => { this.incrementCounter() }}>Increment</button>
                        <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2" onClick={() => { this.incrementCounter() }}>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </CounterContext.Consumer>
        </div>;
    }

    formatCount() {
        const currentCount = this.state.currentCount;
        return currentCount === 0 ? "Zero" : currentCount;
    }

    getBadgeClasses() {
        let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes += this.state.currentCount === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

    incrementCounter() {
        this.setState({
            currentCount: this.state.currentCount + 1
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of your usage of CounterContext here, so sorry if I've misread the question.

When you say 'state passed down' - do you mean you're attempting to update the state and display the updated state?

To do so you'll need to initialise your state with a constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentCount: 7
    };
  };
```

You can then update state with this.setState({}) as you have.

Comment: Sorry I don't think i've worded it very well, what I mean is, that I am passing down state in the <CounterContext.Consumer> block, which I wan't to use instead of my local state of the component, does that make sense?

Comment: I've added a little more info, does that help?  Or do I need to move formatCount out of the component and put this on the context instead?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to move the method you want to call (the one that updates the state) to the `CounterProvider` class. Then pass the method into the state object. After doing that you can now update your `Counter` class to something like so:

```
<CounterContext.Consumer>
   {(c, methodName) =>
     <div className="m-2">
         My name is {c.state.name}
         <button onClick={methodName}></button>
     </div>
   }
</CounterContext.Consumer>
```

Please note that I have used `methodeName` and removed modified the `CounterContext.Consumer` component in order to simplify things.

You can read more about the Context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have changed this to the following, however this has just produced a blank result.  I am not using the function on an onClick, rather to get specific text depending on the counter value.

Comment: <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{formatCount}</span>